# Error MappedByteBuffer is not a valid flatbuffer model in converting model into tf-lite

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-lite

I'm trying to converting deeplab-v3+ model into TF-Lite, I download the pre-trained modals with MobileNet-v2 from [mobilenetv2_coco_voc_trainaug](http://download.tensorflow.org/models/deeplabv3_mnv2_pascal_train_aug_2018_01_29.tar.gz).

using below command to cover the model:

```
bazel run --config=opt \
  //tensorflow/contrib/lite/toco:toco -- \
  --input_file=/tmp/frozen_inference_graph.pb \
  --output_file=/tmp/optimized_graph.tflite \
  --input_format=TENSORFLOW_GRAPHDEF \
  --output_format=TFLITE \
  --input_type=QUANTIZED_UINT8 \
  --input_arrays=ImageTensor \
  --output_arrays=SemanticPredictions \
  --input_shapes=1,513,513,3 \
  --allow_custom_ops
```

it's successfully covered to tflite model, then I put to android asset folder and load to android app, I set below in gradle:

```
aaptOptions {
    noCompress "tflite"
    noCompress "lite"
}
```

using below function to load the model:

```
  /** Memory-map the model file in Assets. */
  private MappedByteBuffer loadModelFile(Activity activity) throws IOException {
    AssetFileDescriptor fileDescriptor = activity.getAssets().openFd(MODEL_PATH);
    FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(fileDescriptor.getFileDescriptor());
    FileChannel fileChannel = inputStream.getChannel();
    long startOffset = fileDescriptor.getStartOffset();
    long declaredLength = fileDescriptor.getDeclaredLength();
    return fileChannel.map(FileChannel.MapMode.READ_ONLY, startOffset, declaredLength);
  }
```

when call `tflite = new Interpreter(loadModelFile(activity));` the issue happen, the exception show "**MappedByteBuffer is not a valid flatbuffer model**"
anyone can help figure out what process I'm doing wrong? Is there a bug in toco tool?

Comment: When I initially tried your command, I got a toco error ("Check failed: output_size_shape.dimensions_count() == 1 (2 vs. 1))" - I think was due to missing ArgMax in toco (https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/15948) and was fixed recently. So I synced to Head and retried, then it succeeded. It could be that fix has still a bug?  OTOH, https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/17468 is still open.

Comment: maybe Converting unsupported operation: Equal and Converting unsupported operation: LogicalAnd cause the issue. I'm confused why Equal and LogicalAnd can't treat as custom_ops

Comment: TOCO assumes that operations that TFLite doesn't have are going to be provided as custom_ops. It seems that you model has these unsupported operations. You should either try to remove them from your model or add custom operations for that. In practice inference models don't usually need Equal operations.

Comment: I solve this issue after implemented TensorflowShape, Equal, LogicalAnd, Expand_dims, Stack OPs

Comment: @Alpha what did you mean by implemented TensorflowShape etc, as i am facing similar issue.

Comment: @Shishram in the latest tensorflow version, all the OPs are implemented. for example TensorflowShape OP commit is https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/commit/4efefb90391b12c95339ed3b46a02b62ea5e195d#diff-b8975ca7bd13576c15d7aa31a67891c2 you can porting back to the your working tensorflow version.

Comment: any valid solutions found for this one ?

Comment: Any solution for this?